# How can you use data from facebook's graph API without having to login?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am creating a personal website about myself and i would like to have it pull images and wall posts from facebook and display them on the page, at the moment this all works fine.....for one hour which is how long an access token lasts for.

I dont want to use access_tokens because the posts and profile picture are public and the point of this website is that it updates itself as i update my facebook profile

Can the facebook API do what i ask of it (which is to allow the photos to be pulled all the time without fear of expiration or even having to log in), or does the facebook API not allow that and is only really used for people wanting to use thair facebook account on your website to comment or like?

I hope i was clear enough...

to summerize, i would like to my website to pull pictures of my profile when people visit the website and not have to deal with access_tokens

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Answer (score 0):

If you configure your "Facebook app" as a "web application" you will get an AppID and an AppSecret. Using these values you can dynamically request a new token every time your page loads and use that token for all of your requests. I believe facebook will return the same token if you continue to request a new token before the old one has expired.

Here is a PHP function to achieve this:

```
public static function GetNewAccessToken(){
        try{
            $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=" .   \Core\Config::FB_APPID . "&client_secret=" . \Core\Config::FB_APPSECRET .  "&grant_type=client_credentials";
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  //to suppress the curl output 
            $response = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);

            //response will be access_code=<CODE> so we need to strip off the access_code part at the front/
            $token = "";
            if (isset($response) && $response !== FALSE && substr($response, 0, 13) === "access_token="){
                $token = substr($response, 13);
            }
            return $token;
        }
        catch(\Exception $exc){
            return "";
        }
}
```